What makes `print(np.half(500.2))` differs from `print(f"{np.half(500.2)}")`
everyone. I've been learning floating-point truncation errors recently. But I found  print(np.half(500.2)) and print(f"{np.half(500.2)}") yield different results. Here are the logs I got in IPython.
In [11]: np.half(500.2)
Out[11]: np.float16(500.2)

In [12]: print(np.half(500.2))
500.2

In [13]: print(f"{np.half(500.2)}")
500.25


I use half.hpp in c++ to compare results with numpy. It seems that 500.2 should be truncated into 500.25 instead of itself.
In binary formats, 500.0 is 0b0_01000_1111010000. So the next float16 number should be 0b_01000_1111010001, which is 500.25 in deximal format.

So what makes print(np.half(500.2)) differs from print(f"{np.half(500.2)}")? Hope to see your answers.

print(np.half(500.2)) shows a simplified, human-readable version (500.2), while f"{np.half(500.2)}" converts the value to Python's float and reveals the actual stored number (500.25) in the limited precision of float16.

Nothing to do with your question, just playing smartass here. But 0b0_01000_1111010000 is 0.01526641845703125 in decimal not 500.25. Your forgot the 15 shift of exponent. see struct.unpack('e', struct.pack('H', 0b0_01000_1111010000)) 500.25 is bin(struct.unpack('H', struct.pack('e', 500.25))[0]) aka 0b0_10111_1111010001 (which is the same, with exponent 8 encoded as 23, with shift of 15). But the error proves that you code floating point by hand, and not a lot do that to understand things ;-)

print calls __str__, while an f-string calls __format__. __format__ with an empty format spec is usually equivalent to __str__, but not all types implement it that way, and numpy.half is one of the types that implements different behavior:
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.half(500.2)

In [3]: str(x)
Out[3]: '500.2'

In [4]: format(x, '')
Out[4]: '500.25'


Precisely, this is where the conversion to float is done _core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c
